# Server Side Data Being Returned as Null on Client

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I tried this in both SignalR and as an API Controller being called with an HttpClient; same results.

When I view the resulting list in the method while debugging, all of the data is there. But, when I view it in the client, Offering and Property are null.

I've tried marking all of the classes as Serializable, tried it in both SingalR and an API controller, ensured the data did not have circular references, tried serializing it manually on the server using Json() in the controller, tried viewing it as a string on the client, which came out as: [{},{},{},{}].

Here is the code:

The LINQ query:

```
[Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public List<OfferingWithProperty> Get(string properties = "0", string inventories = "0")
        {
            var id = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
            var context = _dbContext;
            int[] propertyIds = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(properties).Split(",").ToIntArray();
            int[] inventoryIds = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(inventories).Split(",").ToIntArray();
            var offerings = (from o in context.Offerings!.Include(o => o.InventoryItem).Include(o => o.InventoryItem.Inventory)
                             join om in context.OfferingManagers!
                                 on o.OfferingId equals om.Offering.OfferingId
                             join pom in context.PropertyOfferingMappings!
                                 on o.OfferingId equals pom.Offering!.OfferingId
                             join p in context.Properties!
                                 on pom.Property!.PropertyId equals p.PropertyId
                             join pm in context.PropertyManagers!
                                 on pom.Property!.PropertyId equals pm.Property.PropertyId
                             join i in context.Inventories!
                                on o.InventoryItem.Inventory.InventoryId equals i.InventoryId
                             join ii in context.InventoryItems!.Include("Inventory")
                                 on o.InventoryItem.InventoryItemId equals ii.InventoryItemId
                             join im in context.InventoryManagers!
                                 on o.InventoryItem.Inventory.InventoryId equals im.Inventory.InventoryId
                             where om.UserId == _userManager.GetUserId(User)
                                 && om.Role == OfferingManagerRoles.Administrator
                                 && pm.UserId == _userManager.GetUserId(User)
                                 && pm.Role == PropertyManagerRoles.Administrator
                                 && im.UserId == _userManager.GetUserId(User)
                                 && im.Role == InventoryManagerRoles.Administrator
                                 && propertyIds.Contains(pom.Property!.PropertyId)
                                 && inventoryIds.Contains(o.InventoryItem.Inventory.InventoryId)
                             select new OfferingWithProperty() { Offering = o, Property = p }).ToList();

            return offerings;
        }
```

```
    public class Property
    {
        public Property()
        {
            Name = "";
            Slug = "";
        }
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }
    }

[Serializable]
    public class Offering
    {
        public Offering()
        {
            Name = "";
            Slug = "";
            Description = "";
            InventoryItem = new();
        }
        public int OfferingId { get; set; }
        public InventoryItem InventoryItem { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName="decimal(18,2)")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
```

```
OfferingsWithProperties = await hubConnection.InvokeAsync<List<OfferingWithProperty>>("GetOfferings", propertyIds.ToIntArray(), inventoryIds.ToIntArray());
```

```
string propertyIdString = propertyIds.Count() > 0 ? HttpUtility.UrlEncode(String.Join(',', propertyIds)) : "0";
            string inventoryIdString = inventoryIds.Count() > 0 ? HttpUtility.UrlEncode(String.Join(',', inventoryIds)) : "0";
            var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync($"api/Offering?properties={propertyIdString}&inventories={inventoryIdString}");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this is some technology I'm not familiar with, but shouldn't you be returning an `IActionResult<List<OfferingWithProperty>>` instead of a `List<OfferingWithProperty>`?

Comment: @JohnWu, thank you for your comment. I tried making the change you suggested but received an error (CS0308): "The non-generic type, 'IActionResult' cannot be used with type arguments." Also, when I change the LINQ query to "from o in context.Offerings select o", and change the return type in the method signature, it works (although this is not what I need).

Comment: My apologies. To clarify, when I change the return type in the method signature to List<Offering>, to match the LINQ query type, it works. Not when I change it to IActionResult.

Comment: I'm able to get the data to the client by using an anonymous type on the server with a return type of object, though I'm not able to deserialize it correctly on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a serialization issue. I used an anonymous type in the LINQ query, added Newtonsoft.Json via the NuGet package, used HttpClient.GetStringAsync to call the API Controller, then processed what was returned using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject().

All good now. Thank you!